# jquery input verify value after selecting another element

Tags: jquery, html

Let's say I click an input field and type something into it and then click another input field. How can I get the value I typed into the first input field right when I click something else? I ask this because I want to make a sign up form that verifies the content of the fields after I finish typing something into them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.change()` is your friend. This will log the value from the textbox with ID "input1"

```
$("#input1").change(function() {
    console.log(this.value);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TxEAY/

Answer (score 1):

You can blur / change event to your input field

```
$('#yourId').blur(function(){
     alert(this.value);
});
```